# Match string with placeholder characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

I have a JavaScript application with a string that includes a chain of characters that needs to be matched against given patterns. For example, I have the string `ABCDEFGHI`and the pattern `CDE`, so everytime `CDE` appears in the string, it's a match. So far so good using the `includes()` function.

But some characters in the string act as placeholders for other characters. For example, the letter `Z` can resolve to `C` **or** `D`, so if the search string is `ABZDEFGHI` it should also be a match for the pattern `CDE` since `Z` can resolve to `C`.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem without brute-forcing every single possible combination. Any ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this is exactly what [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) are for.

Comment: your "your_string".match(/your_pattern/ig); will do the work i think

Answer (score 0):

If you want play with string you can start from here:

```
$totalString= "ABCDEFGHIand";
$find="CDE";

$numChar= $find.length;

for ( $i=0; $i< ( $totalString.length - $find.length );$i++ ) {

  $string= $totalString.substring( $i, $i+ $numChar);

  $found=false;
  for ( $j=0; $j < $string.length; $j++) {
  if( $string[$j] != $find[$j] && $string[$j] !== "Z" ) {
  $found=true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( ! $found ) {
      console.log($string);
  }

}
```